# Invariant measure on coset space and integrable functions

Tags: integration, measure-theory, topological-groups, haar-measure

Let $G$ be a locally compact abelian group, and $H$ a closed subgroup.  Let $C_c(G)$ be the space of continuous, compactly supported complex valued functions on $G$.  General theory of Haar measure says that the linear functional

$$\Phi: C_c(G) \rightarrow C_c(G/H)$$

$$\Phi(f)(gH) = \int\limits_H f(gh)dh \tag{1}$$

is surjective and its kernel contains the kernel of the functional $f \mapsto \int\limits_G f(g)dg $ on $C_c(G)$.  Therefore, there is a unique linear functional $\Psi$ on $C_c(G/H)$ such that $\Psi \circ \Phi(f) = \int\limits_G f(g)dg$.  By the Riesz representation theorem, $\Psi$ must be given by a measure on $G/H$, and this measure satisfies

$$\int\limits_G f(g)dg = \int\limits_{G/H} \int\limits_H f(gh)dh dg \tag{2}$$

for all $f \in C_c(G)$.

My question is, what can be said about (2) holding for more general functions, not necessarily compactly supported?  Say, $f$ continuous and in $L^1(G)$.  It isn't obvious that (1) even converges in this case.

If $f$ is continuous and integrable, and (1) converges for all $g \in G$, does (2) hold?

Comment: Why is it not obvious that (1) converges if $f \in L^1(G)$. Doesn't it obviously converge...? As a reminder, $f \in L^1(G)$ implies $\int_G |f(g)|dg < \infty$, so obviously $\int_H |f(gh)|dh < \infty$...

Comment: The Haar measure $dh$ on $H$ is generally not the restriction to $H$ of $dg$, e.g. Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$ and counting measure on $\mathbb Z$